# What are parametric conditions?

Tags: terminology, garch, finance, parameterization, volatility-forecasting

My dissertation supervisor asked me to explain further the following question for a GARCH model:

> "what are the alpha's and the beta's and what are their parametric conditions, and what do the parametric conditions ensure?"

Any idea what this means?

Comment: I am quite familiar with GARCH models but do not immediately recognize the term. If I were you, I would just ask the supervisor for the details.

Comment: A little might be intended to refer to parametric *assumptions.* However, that meaning would not apply in this context, which leaves us all wondering what your supervisor might possibly have meant.

Comment: Seems like you've been asked a riddle. Given the context, my guess is that they are asking for the usual stationarity conditions involving the persistence (e.g. $\alpha + \beta < 1$ or whatever), but I would probably ask for clarification.